# How can I diagnose a process which has no executable file name associated with it?

Tags: process, tracing

There is a process taking up 100% CPU on a KVM based server I am running.

This is the output of htop.

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command                 
22230 adminx     20   0  185M  3468  1600 S 100.  0.5 72h45:33 apache 
22232 adminx     20   0  185M  3468  1600 R 100.  0.5 72h45:12 apache 
10660 root       20   0 26880  4680  3176 R  0.0  0.6  0:00.11 htop
 1061 root       20   0  276M  5796     0 S  0.0  0.8  0:05.59 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
 9529 root       20   0 92796  6916  5992 S  0.7  0.9  0:00.11 sshd: root@pts/3
```

The process name is `apache` and the user is `adminx`. There shouldn't be any apache executeable on the system and the user `adminx` shouldn't be running it in any case.

The output of `strace` on the two pids is show below.

`strace -p 22230`

```
epoll_wait(7, [], 1024, 204)            = 0
epoll_wait(7, [], 1024, 34)             = 0
epoll_wait(7, [], 1024, 500)            = 0
epoll_wait(7, [], 1024, 465)            = 0
epoll_wait(7, [], 1024, 34)             = 0
......
```

`strace -p 22232`

```
sched_yield()                           = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
......
```

I don't know how the process originated and the server may have been hacked. I have killed the process and I plan on reinstalling the server.

Given something of this nature how to you trace how the process started, if there is no executable by that name? How can the memory image of the executable be captured for analysis, and how can its memory allocations be analyzed?

PS. I found the name of the executable. It seems it is copied to shared memory and deleted.

```
adminx@gw06  ~  ls -l /proc/10160/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adminx adminx 0 Jun  3 09:22 /proc/10160/exe -> /dev/shm/apache (deleted)
```

Comment: capture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789550/saving-core-file-in-gdb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That may be bitcoin mining malware.

You can check the executable with

```
ls -l /proc/22230/exe
```

The name of that file may be different. The process can set its `$0` which is shown in e.g. `top`.